# .net remote fetching of registry values

Tags: .net, powershell, registry

I am trying to get the Windows 10 minor build number from a remote PC using .net. This is the Powershell command I use:

```
[Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey([Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive]::LocalMachine, 192.168.78.103).OpenSubKey('Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion').GetValue('UBR')
```

It seems to work fine at first glance, but I just realized that it does not actually fetch the remote PCs value but the one from my local PC. I searched around and many people already reported that this command works fine, but it doesn't for me.

I haven't really used a lot of .net before, do I have to tweak some settings on either the local or the remote machine for this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second parameter is a string so will need to be enclosed in quotes:

```
[Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey([Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive]::LocalMachine, "192.168.78.103").OpenSubKey('Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion').GetValue('UBR')
```

[RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registrykey.openremotebasekey?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0)

*The local machine registry is opened if machineName is String.Empty. The requested key must be a root key on the remote machine, and is identified by the appropriate RegistryHive value.*

Comment: Tried that with 'quotes' and "double quotes", but in both cases it can't find the network path.

Comment: That seems like a different problem from your original question. Check that you can actually connect remotely using regedit.

Comment: Thanks a lot, fixed it: RemoteRegistry service wasn't running on the remote PC